# Why am I getting a crash when exiting my Activity?

Tags: java, android, crash, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am experiencing a crash in my app when I quit (via the back button) out of my Activity. So far as I can tell this is happening in the Android codebase and not mine, but I'm not completely convinced of that.

Here's the stacktrace from adb:

```
AndroidRuntime  E  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
AndroidRuntime  E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {MyApp/MyApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3097)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:112)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
AndroidRuntime  E      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime  E      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
AndroidRuntime  E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
AndroidRuntime  E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
AndroidRuntime  E      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime  E  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3575)
AndroidRuntime  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
AndroidRuntime  E      ... 11 more
```

Anyone have any ideas/recommendations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can't help much, as there's no code.
Still looking at

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3575)

I just checked Activity.java

```
       final int N = mManagedCursors.size();
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            ManagedCursor mc = mManagedCursors.get(i); 
            if (!mc.mReleased) {
                mc.mCursor.deactivate(); // line 3575
                mc.mReleased = true;
            }
        }
```

Are you sure all cursors are released properly?

Comment: I think they should be managed by the Activity... I've called startManagingCursor() on the only Cursor I'm using. Shouldn't this handle that?

Comment: From the docs: This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is, when the activity is stopped it will automatically call deactivate() on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call requery() for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors will be closed automatically.

Comment: Isn't that actually exactly what the code you posted should be doing?

Comment: Oh wait... I bet the cursor object IS null... duh. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yep, that was it. It had no problems "binding" to a null, but when it was trying to free it it was throwing an exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Excellent explanation of what's going on inside during this situation: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-activityperformstop.html

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity before startManagingCursor() method is called , your Cursor is null. Dont let the Cursor be null.