# Android: performStop() NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, background, crash, sleep

I have a trouble with the app crashed after sleeping mode (for 20-30 min and longer).  I've tried some tweaking but nothing helps:

[Why am I getting a crash when exiting my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376783/why-am-i-getting-a-crash-when-exiting-my-activity)

[Why is my activity crashing when hitting the home button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891100/why-is-my-activity-crashing-when-hitting-the-home-button)

http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-activityperformstop.html

here is some crashlogs which i got through android market from the users

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {/*my activity class*/}:            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {/*my activity class*/}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2694)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity     {/*my activity class*/}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2586)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(LocalActivityManager.java:622)
at android.app.ActivityGroup.onDestroy(ActivityGroup.java:85)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     /*my activity class*/.onStop(/*my activity class*/.java:141)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1170)
at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3873)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2623)
... 15 more
```

at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3873) - instead of line 3873 can bee 3899,  4073, 4532

Comment: Can you show us the `onStop` code?

Comment: it is native:  public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
 }

Comment: what is FlurryAgent? Did you check if it is null?

Comment: [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html). yes, it isnt null. its not an object even